# How can you export the saved username and passwords in FireFox 2?

Tags: firefox

I need to reformat my machine but I have so many user/passwords stored in FF2 that I just keep putting it off. Yes I know about backing up the entire profile and restoring it. But for some reason my profile has many issues and I want to start fresh with that as well.

Are the username and passwords stored in a text file or is there some way to export them and import after I reformat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a Firefox add-on called [Password Exporter](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2848). It can export to XML or CSV files that can be imported in another browser or computer.

Answer (score 5):

I've had luck just copying `signons2.txt` and `key3.db` over from one profile to another. See also [the documentation on MozillaZine](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Signons.txt).

Answer (score 2):

This extension will do it for you:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2848

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Foxmarks](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2410) plugin. This exports to XML or CSV format. I used it a week ago and it works really fine.

Answer (score 0):

Alas, this won't solve the re-importing problem, but check out http://wejn.org/stuff/moz-export.html

They have a single html page with a small javascript section that exports your passwords. Save the html to your desktop, read through to make sure it's not evil, open the page in FF, save the results.

Maybe I'm paranoid, but I'm not sure I'd trust a password-exporting extension...

Answer (score 0):

You can use third party tools (like PasswordFox) available to export saved passwords from Firefox but many people don’t believe in third party tools because this is the matter of high security so, it is better to use Firefox add-on rather than third party tool.

Password Exporter Firefox extension is the best solution to export and import saved passwords safely and quickly. You can install Password Exporter from below URL.

http://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/password-exporter and see the [full documentation of installation and uses.](http://itbloggertips.com/2014/06/how-to-export-saved-passwords-from-firefox/)